# Why am I getting disconnected: not connected to DevTools error with Python Selenium ChromeDriver?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, error-handling, selenium-chromedriver

I am using selenium to get the names of everybody at this website: [USTA site](https://www.usta.com/en/home/play/rankings.html#tab=junior&junior-rankListGender=M&junior-ageRestriction=Y14&junior-juniorListType=seeding)

(I am one of those junior tennis players so it's not creepy)

Once I get the names, I open a ChromeDriver and use a for loop to enter them into the search bar, click on their row, get their data (WTN rating), go back, and work with the next name.

The clicking and collecting data part works anywhere from 1-4 minutes and then just disconnects and doesn't do anything. After I close the driver, it gives me this:
[image: img1]
and then:
[image: img2]

I deleted my previous chromedriver and installed version 119.0.6045.105. I have chrome version 119.0.6045.124, but there isn't a chromedriver for it.

This is the code I have to click and collect data:

```
for n in name_list:
    for letter in n:
        if letter in ['.','/']:
            letter.pop()
    try:
        driver.maximize_window()
        driver.execute_script('window.scrollTo(0,0)')
        search = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='container-9a770322f5']/div/div/div/div/input"))
        )
        #search.click()
        search.clear()
        search.send_keys(n)
    finally:
        pass
        

    try:
        profile = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='container-c80bd54915']/div/div[4]/div/div[2]"))
        )
        if profile.text == n:
            profile.click()
        else:
            time.sleep(1)
            profile.click()
    except:
        try:
            driver.quit()
            driver = webdriver.Chrome()
            driver.get("https://www.usta.com/en/home/play/rankings.html#tab=junior&junior-rankListGender=M&junior-ageRestriction=Y14&junior-juniorListType=seeding")
            try:
                driver.maximize_window()
                driver.execute_script('window.scrollTo(0,0)')
                search = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
                    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='container-9a770322f5']/div/div/div/div/input"))
                )
                search.clear()
                search.send_keys(n)
                try:
                    profile = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
                        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='container-c80bd54915']/div/div[4]/div/div[2]"))
                    )
                    if profile.text == n:
                        profile.click()
                    else:
                        time.sleep(1)
                        profile.click()
                finally:
                    pass
                    #search.click()
            finally:
                pass
        except:
            wtn_list.append('err')
            dubs_wtn_list.append('err')
            continue
    finally:
        pass


    try:
        wtn = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='wtnwidget-fbdae59336']/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/p"))
        )
        wtn_list.append(str(wtn.text))
        
    except:
        wtn_list.append("err")
        pass
    finally:
        pass


    try:
        dubs_wtn = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='wtnwidget-fbdae59336']/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/p"))
        )
        dubs_wtn_list.append(str(dubs_wtn.text))
        driver.back()
    except:
        driver.back()
        dubs_wtn_list.append('err')
    finally:
        pass

    try:
        search = WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='container-9a770322f5']/div/div/div/div/input"))
        )
        search.clear()
    except:
        driver.back()
        

    
    

driver.quit()
```

It worked fine a couple days ago and I looked all over Stack Overflow so I really do not know.